# Spark to parse backslash escaped comma in CSV files that are not enclosed by quotes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Seems spark is not able to escape characters in CSV files that are not enclosed by quotes, for example,

```
Name,Age,Address,Salary
Luke,24,Mountain View\,CA,100
```

I am using pyspark, the following code apparently won't work with the comma inside Address field.

```
df = spark.read.csv(fname, schema=given_schema,
                sep=',', quote='',mode="FAILFAST")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may use the same approach as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131663/how-to-parse-a-file-with-newline-character-escaped-with-and-not-quoted?rq=1

Comment: @ManojSingh Thanks! I'll try that, but it's too bad we can't use the read.csv API - that's a preferred approach in our application.

Comment: All right, the format is not compatible with RFC 4180: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180. I guess my application can say "NO" firmly to files like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please give a try using rdd first, reformat it and then create a dataframe over it.

```
df  = sc.textFile(PATH_TO_FILE) \
    .map(lambda x: x.replace("\\," ,"|")) \
    .mapPartitions(lambda line: csv.reader(line,delimiter=','))\
    .filter(lambda line: line[0] != 'Name') \
    .toDF(['Name','Age','Address','Salary'])
```

this is how your dataframe looks like now:

```
>>> df.show();
+----+---+----------------+------+
|Name|Age|         Address|Salary|
+----+---+----------------+------+
|Luke| 24|Mountain View|CA|   100|
+----+---+----------------+------+
```

I have to replace address column "\," with "|" and then I splitted the data using delimiter ','. Not sure how it matches your requirement but it's working.